# PHP Upload form, PDF, Doc & Docx

Tags: php, html, upload

I'm struggling to make this upload code work for a docx file, it works okay for doc and pdf..

```
$allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc", "docx");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
 {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
 {
   echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
 }
```

this is part of a project from a while ago and i honestly can't remember how to do it..

I know it's not the most secure upload method, but if someone could help it would be appreciated!

I'm thinking i need to add another line here:

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)
```

Just not sure what.. Help is appreciated!

Edit:
So i've got to this stage (with the help of comments!)

```
$allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc", "docx");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
//if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
//|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword"))
if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf") 
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword") 
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-    officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)

&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
```

But now its coming up with: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND in /var/sites/s/stanation.com/public_html/forms/process/insert.php on line 30

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For `docx` check this MIME type

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

EDIT :

Here's the code . You're missing parenthesis

```
<?php

    $allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc", "docx");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
      {
         echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "Success";
      }
  }
```

Comment: Yeah i found some details on that, i just can't figure out how to add it into the allowed types? Any idea? It's been a long time since i've done any php so i'm very rusty!

Comment: @AliClarke Try to add `|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"))` below `|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword"))`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Looks like we both pasted at the same time. LOL

Comment: Looks like we're getting closer.. get this error now. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND in /var/sites/s/stanation.com/public_html/forms/process/insert.php on line 30

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Lol :) . I deleted mine.

Comment: @AliClarke, Can you paste the code ? Seems like you are missing some parenthesis.

Comment: I've added it to the question above, cheers for the help (or http://pastebin.com/fz0VXzQK)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Ah, great minds think alike ;-) (`+1`) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This following check will help you to upload `.docx` files:

```
$_FILES["txtFile"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do the task. 
Just check the file type and then you can work further.

Here is code to check the filetype.

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$filename= $_FILES["fileupload"]["name"]; //gets filename with type
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($filename); //uploads/file.type
echo $target_file;
$extension= pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
$imageFileType = strtolower($extension);
if(strcmp($imageFileType,"docx")==0){
    echo "Its word file";
}
```