# php simple upload files not working

Tags: php, upload

I'm currently working on an extremely simplistic PHP file upload, but it fails to do anything at all.  There is nothing in the specified directory.

PHP on the submit of my HTML form:

```
<?php

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
    //error
    echo "Something went wrong";
}
else
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}

?>
```

I suspect that something may be up with the fact that I'm using GoDaddy, since they've been quirky with php features in the past.

EDIT:  Fixed underscore;
now I'm getting an actual error.

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/uploads/asd.docx) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/09/11461509/html/php/upload.php on line 11

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpSIA5Jv' to '/uploads/asd.docx' in /home/content/09/11461509/html/php/upload.php on line 11
```

Comment: You may need to change `"/uploads/"` to `"uploads/"` without the leading slash. You're presently using an absolute path, when you should be using a relative path. Most likely the issue here. Also check to see after, if the folder is writeable.

Comment: also move_uploaded_file($FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); is wrong u have FILES should be $_FILES

Comment: try to debug using `print_r` or `var_dump` you can find the problem

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: oops, I'll take a look to see if that fixes anything.  Fred: I'm aware it's absolute; uploads is a folder in my root.

Comment: Change `move_uploaded_file($FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],` to `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],` - Abhik picked that one up. You have the missing underscore between `$` and `FILES`. @AlexanderLozada

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- these are small sort of typo that sometime make it hard to find the issue and we think code is good but still does not work :)

Comment: It's the "little things that count" ;-) @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: Alright, I fixed the underscore, and I updated the question with an error I'm now receiving.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? @AlexanderLozada and what permissions is the folder set to?

Comment: hmm make sure that the folder is web writable..

Comment: You're running your code from a different folder "`php`", from what I've gathered by your error messages. @AlexanderLozada Try running the code from the root of your server, and then use `uploads` as your uploading folder.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's it!  No idea why, but it works now.  If you make this an answer I'll select it, thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I posted it below Alexander. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21494728/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running your code from a different folder `"php"`, from what I've gathered by your error messages. Try running the code from the root of your server, and then use `uploads` as your uploading folder.

Also make sure the folder has the proper write permissions set. Usually `755` and sometimes `777` although `755` is a safer setting.

---

As per OP's [`original posted code`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21494673/1)

Missing underscore between `$` and `FILES`

```
move_uploaded_file($FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                 ---^
```

---

```
<?php

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
    //error
    echo "Something went wrong";
}
else
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the `enctype` in form tag as `multipart/form-data` and PHP code should as follows-

First make sure that your files has been uploaded successfully in temp directory, then try to debug upload path and finally file moving functionality to specific directory.

```
<?php

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    //error
    echo "Something went wrong";
} else {
// try echoing the following codes first-
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

// then try to debug upload path
// move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
// take move_uploaded_file(); in a variable and then print_r($variable);
}

?>
```

I am referring you to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814559/php-upload-form-pdf-doc-docx) for upload problem the `docx` file using PHP.

Comment: PHP echoed:
Upload: asd.docx
Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
Stored in: /tmp/phpcWdZU4

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

please write in form tag `enctype="multipart/form-data"`